# Akka HTTP server: Acceptor thread in blocked state

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am running Akka HTTP server, where I observe that under load "Acceptor1" and "Acceptor2" threads are always in blocked state. Below is a excerpt from the thread dump.
Why are the acceptors in blocked state? What is a way to increase the number of acceptors?

"qtp1907228381-105 Acceptor1 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000" prio=5 tid=105 BLOCKED
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:938)
       local variable: java.lang.String#54885
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
       local variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor#2
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this means it is waiting for more connections to arrive - it's typically not an indication of a problem